# Gravatar not consistent between sites

Tags: support, gravatar

For some reason, my gravatar identicon is not consistent between sites.

On most Stackexchange sites, my avatar is what is seen below.  For clarity, this image.

[image]

But on the [Politics beta](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/1652/compro01), it has changed itself to a different one, without anything being changed.  No changes to avatar settings, no change to email address, nothing.  And it appears to be only that site, none of the others show this changed avatar.  I'm not sure when exactly this happened, as I'm not that active on Politics and don't generally look at my own avatar much in general.

[image]

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the email address field isn't perhaps *empty* there?

Comment: The image is purely based on the link to the image; Stack Exchange generates the URL based on your email address, and if it is missing, from your last known ip address. The URL is clearly different, so different information was used to generate the URL hash.

Comment: Your 'normal' hash is e38af591e688a29bbcbb42fa524f0df5, but for Politics it is 27e03c6e9d42fce89015665ee358dd5c. I cannot see your email address nor your IP address, so I cannot say which piece of info was used as the basis here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - The email address field is filled and it is the same both here and on politics.